# Dynamically create REST test steps in groovy

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I have some JSON file that I want to use as input, let's consider that I have this folders

```
mainFolder --> Folder 1 : 10 JSON file (req)
           --> Folder 2 : 10 JSON file (req)
```

I want to create from these folders : - Each directory is a testCase - Each file is a testStep

Here's my code :

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.GroovyScriptStepFactory
import com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.RestRequestStepFactory
import com.eviware.soapui.config.TestStepConfig
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.*;

def myTestCase = context.testCase
log.info myTestCase


def projectPath = Path
def endPoint = "anEndPoint";


def addTestStep(operation, requestFile, testCase, projectPath, endpoint){

    def usageId = requestFile.name.replace("_request.json","")
    def projectPathTest = projectPath+"SPecificPath";
    def testStepName=usageId;

    def iface = testCase.testSuite.project.getInterfaceList()[0];
    def operationName= operation;
    def op = iface.operations[operationName];
    def config = com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.RestRequestStepFactory.createConfig( op, testStepName);

    def newTestStep = testCase.addTestStep( config );
    newTestStep.getTestRequest().setRequestContent(requestFile.text)
    newTestStep.httpRequest.endpoint = endpoint
}

if ( com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport.confirm("Reconstruct ?","Confirm") ){

    testSuite.getTestCaseList().each{testCase->testSuite.removeTestCase(testCase)}

    new File(projectPathTest).eachDir{dir->  
        operation = dir.name
        def RestTestCase = testSuite.addNewTestCase(operation)
        RestTestCase.setFailOnError(false)
        dir.eachFileMatch(~/.*_request\.json/){file->
        addTestStep(operation, file, RestTestCase, projectPath, endPoint)       
        }
    }
}
```

I verified many times, many pages, many forums, it seems that I have the correct form and algorithm to get what I want, instead, I succeed to create testCase with the names of the folders, I succeed to get the request JSON file, but I fail to create the test step, and I'm pretty sure it's either the config or interface/operation who make it fail :

```
def config = com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.RestRequestStepFactory.createConfig( op, testStepName);
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace? And are you expecting to create 20 test cases?

Comment: @rao Well i'm not an expert on REST, so I'm just the raw and json request (stored in a file) I did the same algorithm for SOAP request with xml input files  and it works
As for test cases number, I'm expecting to do 2 test cases with 10 steps each

Comment: Well, that might helped you with soap requests. Isn't simple to add a rest step and do the data driven test for all the data using groovy script instead of creating the step itself?

Comment: Well that might help, yes, it's more "beautiful" to see all the test steps created, but yes I'll go this way, thanks anyway